# Swift Guard-Let Statement snippet

Tags: swift, xcode, code-snippets

Why autocomplete for `guardlet` snippet doesn't work in closures? For example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    guardlet //no any suggestions by Xcode
})
```

Shouldn't I use this control statement in any closure? Or it's just wrong scopes in the snippet?

I'm using Xcode 8.2 (8C38).

Comment: It is not guardlet it is guard let.

Comment: I'm asking about Xcode snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It works in Xcode 8.2.1:

[image: guardlet snippet]

Make sure you do not have pending compilation errors in your project.
You can close Xcode and reopen it eventually.

Comment: I've updated my question, I have previous version of Xcode. I'll update it and try.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Please share your project, and I'll try. Or kill Xcode, clear DerivedData, empty the trash, re-open Xcode and wait for the cache to rebuild.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov there are known cases in Swift where the code is so ambiguous for Xcode, that it takes years to be understood, effectively freezing Xcode autocompletion. Some of those cases are available on [cocoawithlove](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/07/12/type-checker-issues.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
 guard let x = x where x > 0 else {
   // Value requirements not met, do something
 }
})
```

N.B:- Hi,there are no such key available "guardlet" in xcode please write that code"guard let"

Comment: I know about syntax of `guard` construction syntax, I'm asking about snippet.